# How to improve richness of digital sound imported from cassette tape?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, audacity, sound-editing

I successfully used a cassette-to-USB converter to import some of my wife's songs from 1992 into my computer, via Audacity.  The sound quality is decent, but I'd like to make it sound as rich and full as possible.  I understand that I can't create something better than the original, but I'd like to do whatever I can to make it sound more dynamically full (i.e. less tinny).  Are there any filters or other tricks that I can employ to do this?

Comment: Re-record it with the bass turned up from your amplifier?

Comment: Did you pay attention to Dolby (recordings with or without Dolby, does the convert support Dolby, etc.)? Did you look at the spectrogram for the passages that sound tinny? Did you try equalizer settings according to what you see in the spectrogram? Did you pay attention to correct level settings when capturing?

Comment: tbh, you're asking for an entire university degree in 3 paragraphs. Audio cleanup & restoration is big business. You can pay people to do it for you. Some of the software required to do it will set you back 5 grand [though you can rent it for 5 days at a mere 200 bucks] If you want to just have a play at it, look into de-noise, de-click, de-crackle, de-hum software to get you started, then at dynamic compressor/expanders, preferably multiband. Waves make a whole restoration bundle - https://www.waves.com/bundles/restoration - with all the de-xx. They also make some very good multiband comps.

Comment: BTW - sure you can create something better than the original. it's done all the time. Listen to the Beatles 24-bit remasters for one exemplary project.